# Actix Token Auth for Scope

Tags: rust, actix-web

I made a Actix Webserver which includes a scope ("/api") with a few routes.

Now I want to expose the API but I want to limit the access via tokens and I found a way to do it by getting the body in a route and checking if the token is correct ...

```rust
#[post("/test")]
async fn write_content(req_body: String) -> impl Responder {
    let body_str = req_body.to_string();
    let body: WriteContentBody = serde_json::from_str(&body_str).unwrap();

    // of course I will make it in the future with a db ... this is just for getting the basics
    if body.token === "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" {
        HttpResponse::Ok().body("200")
    } else {
        HttpResponse::Ok().body("401")
    }
}
```

but I basically want to do it for my whole scope which includes a few routes without making this check in every route.

something like

```rust
App::new()
    .service(
        web::scope("/api")
        .before_check(token_check)
        .service(index)
        .service(test)
        .service(get_content)
        .service(write_content)
        .service(new_project)
        .service(list_projects)
   )
```